# Combine list of lists of matrices into a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, apply

I have a relatively large list. Each element of the list is a list of six elements. Each of these elements is a matrix with a fixed number of rows and a variable number of columns. I would like to combine the matrices such that I end up with one list of six matrices where each matrix is the result of calling cbind on the corresponding elements from each sub-list i.e. The first matrix is a cbind of all first matrices from the inner lists, the second matrix is a cbind of the second matrices, etc.

For instance:

```
 temp = list()
 temp[["a"]] = list(matrix(1, nrow=2, ncol=1), matrix(2, nrow=2,ncol=2))
 temp[["b"]] = list(matrix(3, nrow=2, ncol=3), matrix(4, nrow=2,ncol=4))
```

**call some R code** should result in the output of

```
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    3    3
[2,]    1    3    3    3

$`3`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    2    4    4    4    4
[2,]    2    2    4    4    4    4
```

I can see that calling

```
mapply(cbind, temp[[1]], temp[[2]])
```

produces the desired output for this toy example, but do I do it for a large list, with a possibly variable number elements from execution to execution.

Is there an elegant and performant solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purrr::pmap` iterates in parallel over list items and passes to the function you specify, so you can obtain your desired results with just

```
library(purrr)

temp %>% pmap(cbind)
## [[1]]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    3    3    3
## [2,]    1    3    3    3
## 
## [[2]]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    2    2    4    4    4    4
## [2,]    2    2    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: This appears to me to be the best solution. It's both fast (under 1 minute on my input) and succinct.

Answer (score 2):

```
do.call(mapply, c(cbind, temp))
```

Comment: I like this because it only uses the built-in functions and is succinct. It works as designed on the toy example, although after about 20 minutes it hasn't completed on my real input. This is actually longer than it takes me to generate my data so may not be acceptable from a performance standpoint.

I'm a little confused by what's actually going on in your solution though. Would you mind explaining how it works? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `transpose` from `purrr` and `cbind`

```
library(purrr)
lapply(transpose(temp), function(x) do.call(cbind, x))
```

---

Or we can just use `transpose` with `map` from `purrr`

```
transpose(temp) %>% 
            map(~matrix(unlist(.), nrow=2))
#[[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    3    3
#[2,]    1    3    3    3

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    2    2    4    4    4    4
#[2,]    2    2    4    4    4    4
```

---

We can also try with the `split` option

```
library(data.table)
with(melt(temp), lapply(split(value, L1), matrix, nrow=2))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
lst <- lapply(1:1e5, function(x) replicate(2, matrix(sample(1:5, 10, 
   replace=TRUE), nrow=2), simplify = FALSE))

system.time({

 do.call(mapply, c(cbind, lst))

})
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.66    0.00    0.65 

system.time({
  lst %>% pmap(cbind)

})
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.61    0.00    0.61 

system.time({
  lapply(transpose(lst), function(x) do.call(cbind, x))
})
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.39    0.00    0.40 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Hong = do.call(mapply, c(cbind, lst)),
   ae = lst %>% pmap(cbind),
   akrun =  lapply(transpose(lst), function(x) do.call(cbind, x)), 
   unit = "relative")
#    Unit: relative
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   Hong 1.716893 2.346379 1.975948 2.069316 2.012889 1.288478   100
#     ae 1.623129 2.096566 1.697061 1.805834 1.702961 1.193930   100
#  akrun 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```